# Restrict certain search keywords in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I would like to stop users from using the * wildcard in sharepoint. They are welcome to use them at the end of a term such as anthon* but not * alone as a search term. How could I do this with Sharepoint settings?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "Complete Matching" in managed properties. By default , the Complete Matching setting is disabled and so when you  use just a part of a word, from the beginning of the word, by using the wildcard operator (*), the prefix matching will be enabled. In prefix matching, Search in SharePoint 2013 matches results with terms that contain the word followed by zero or more characters.  Once you enable Complete Matching , queries will only be matched against the exact content of the property.

So, for your requirements, you need to enable complete matching for all managed properties.
[image]